# Joint Probability Density (Graphing)

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions, multiple-integral

If the joint probability density of $X$ and $Y$ is given by

$$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{y},0<x<y,0<y<1 &  &  & \\ 
 0, elsewhere&  &  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Find $P(X+Y>\frac{1}{2})$

How should I graph it so that I could know what to integrate? Hope someone can provide a graph with explanations. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[$\{(x,y): 0<x<y<1, x+y>1/2\}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+0%3Cx%3Cy%3C1+and+y%3E1%2F2-x+where+x%3D0+to+1) is the interior of the polygon: [$(1/4,1/4)(0,1/2)(0,1)(1,1)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7B%7B1%2F4,1%2F4%7D,%7B0,1%2F2%7D,%7B0,1%7D,%7B1,1%7D,%7B1%2F4,1%2F4%7D%7D)

Its the upper-left section of the unit square cut by the lines $y=x, y=1/2-x$ .